# Godel's incompleteness theorem when the cardinality of axioms is > ℵ_0?

Tags: logic, truth, goedel

So I was thinking of Godel's theorem (I am by no means an expert in this topic). Does Godel's only work when the cardinality of the number of axioms is the same as the cardinality of the number of integers?

Secondly is there a proof that let's say I have a finite number of axioms. Now no matter what I do I cannot re-axiomatize the such that the cardinality classes of my first set of axioms and the second set of axioms are different?

Comment: The cardinality of *all* sentences of any first order theory is the same as the cardinality of integers, countable. So if you allow countably many axioms you can trivially get a complete theory, just make every true sentence an axiom. Of course, this is also completely uninteresting, it tells us nothing new as to which sentences are actually true.

Comment: @Conifold Ignoring trivial cases (i.e. an empty alphabet), the cardinality of the set of sentences in a first order theory is either countable or equal to the cardinality of the underlying alphabet (whichever is larger), and the alphabet can have uncountable many relation, function and/or constant symbols.

Comment: @Sam Humanly relevant alphabets are finite or recursive, one would encounter the same problem with listing non-recursive alphabets as with listing all true sentences.

Comment: @Conifold You said **any** first order theory, and the only restriction there is to have enough symbols to build the formulas. As for "humanly relevant", it's not a well defined criterion, is it?

Comment: @Sam Why not? A God can, perhaps, pick out infinite sets of sentences or alphabet symbols without any recursive rule to generate them, a human cannot. So either move is the same pretense that "achieves" more by making it pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping things reasonably simple at the cost of some generality, Godel's (first) incompleteness theorem says the following:

> There is no complete consistent computably axiomatizable theory in the language of (say) arithmetic extending (say) Robinson arithmetic, Q.

Since there are only countably many sentences in the language of arithmetic *at all*, there are no uncountable axiom systems to which Godel applies. Moreover, since Godelian incompleteness crucially involves the notion of *computability*, it's not even clear how to pose the relevant question for uncountable languages in the first place.

That said, the finite/infinite alternate axiomatization question you ask does have a snappy answer. Going a bit more general, suppose T is a finitely axiomatizable extension of Q. Let P={p_i: i<k} be a finite axiomatization of T and let S={s_n: n\in N} be an infinite axiomatization of T. Then for each i<k there is some j_i such that the conjunction of s_1 through s_{j_i} proves p_i; but then the finite initial segment {s_n: n<=max{j_i: i<k}} of S already axiomatizes T. So **no finitely axiomatizable theory has a non-redundant infinite axiomatization**.

(Note that this last observation crucially uses the fact that, in first-order logic, *proofs are finite*. In general the result above works for, and only for, the **compact** logics. For example, in second-order logic we can axiomatize the second-order theory of the countably infinite pure set either with a single second-order sentence saying "The domain is infinite and countable" or via the infinite second-order theory saying "The domain is *finite or* countable" + "The domain has size at least n" for each finite n. Once we lose compactness, we give up some stability - or, more positively, we *gain* some flexibility.)